# GitHub freezes on compare or pull request Firefox Developer Edition

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, github

When I try to create a pull request on GitHub for one of the private repositories I contribute to, Firefox hangs and crashes badly enough that I need to kill the process or wait several minutes for the page to respond again. I am currently on Ubuntu 16.04 and using Firefox Developer Edition (64-bit).

Comment: if it really is a *crash* then firefox should have a crash report under `about:crashes`

Comment: I appear to have used the word crash incorrectly, I meant that it simply stops responding and needs to be manually killed as it has frozen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While contacting GitHub support was helpful, I attempted all of the steps suggested including disabling all add-ons, killing plugins like Flash, and using another browser. I was able to get a pull request to properly display in Chrome, and then worked on getting Firefox to respond similarly and discovered that there is a preference on the General tab called "Enable Multi-process Firefox Developer Edition" that I had enabled at some point, and when I disabled that option, the hanging issue disappeared. I was able to re-enable all of my add-ons and plugins and while there is a momentary hang when doing a compare, that matches the hang seen in Chrome which I assume is doing some minor background checking and re-rendering the page. Hopefully this helps someone else having a similar issues, especially since the Developer Edition has some nifty tools that I think others will have the same problem.